# sp_execute does not support dynamic SQL query with more than 4000 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using `sp_execute` statement to execute a dynamic SQL query.

But `sp_execute` does not support dynamic SQL query with more than 4000 characters.

It is working fine with the `EXEC` statement, though.

Please suggest if you have any solution.

This is my code:

```
declare @a nvarchar(max), @b nvarchar(max), @c nvarchar(max), @d nvarchar(max)

select @d = 'a'
select @a = 'select top 1 name,''', @b = replicate(@d, 10000),
       @c=''' from sysobjects'

SELECT LEN(@a + @b + @c)

DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(max) = @a + @b + @c

EXEC sp_execute @s
EXEC(@s)
```

Comment: You need [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `sp_executesql`. It supports nvarchar(max). You may refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

But your issue is not so much with `sp_execute` but with the string `@b`. If you do notice, the following query gives len of 8036 and not 10036

```
SELECT len(@a+@b+@c)
```

The culprit is `@b=replicate('a',10000)` the length max at 8000. Replicate returns the same data type of `a` which is `varchar`

if you cast or convert() the string `a` to nvarchar(max), it will gives you 1000 characters

```
@b = replicate(convert(nvarchar(max), 'a'),10000)
```

or you may also try this

```
declare @d nvarchar(max)

select @d = 'a'
select @b = replicate(@d, 10000)
select len(@b)
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I have updated my questions , but still it is not working with EXEC sp_execute @s

Comment: Please go through my answer. It stated to use `sp_executesql` and not `sp_execute`

Answer (score 1):

Use `sp_executesql` instead of `sp_execute`.

```
declare @a nvarchar(max), @b nvarchar(max), @c nvarchar(max), @d nvarchar(max)

select @d = 'a'
select @a = 'select top 1 name,''', @b = replicate(@d, 10000),
       @c=''' from sysobjects'

SELECT LEN(@a + @b + @c)

DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(max) = @a + @b + @c

EXEC sp_executesql @s
EXEC(@s)
```